# Can't install Hyperledger Sawtooth due to strange python dependency

Tags: python, ubuntu, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to install sawtooth on my almost fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.  I added the latest sawtooth repository and I used the following command:

```
sudo apt install sawtooth
```

It gives me the following output:

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sawtooth : Depends: python3-sawtooth-cli but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-intkey but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-rest-api but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-sdk but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-validator but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: python3-sawtooth-xo but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Digging in to those packages, I reach the following package:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-secp256k1 : Depends: python3 (< 3.7) but 3.8.2-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This error message is honestly insane to me.  I have Python 3.8.10, so this shouldn't be a problem.

I was wondering if there is a known fix.  I have looked at existing more general solutions to this, but they don't seem to work.

EDIT:  To check my sanity on this, I created a completely fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a virtual machine.  I did nothing on the machine except what is in the guide below.  I encountered the exact same error.  This is a completely unaltered machine.

https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html

Comment: You might have multiple python versions installed. Please check which of them is set as the default one to pick up.

Comment: I do have Python 3.7.12, but I downloaded it after I encountered this problem.  It did not solve the issue.

Comment: To be clearer, I tried installing that version of python and made it the default python installation.  It did not fix the issue, so I reverted the default back to 3.8.10.